# Will you be installing Windows 7 RC as your primary OS?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Will you be installing Windows 7 RC as your primary OS?  Or be waiting for the RTM version?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a poll - please don't add a new "yes" "maybe" or "no" answer - add a comment instead and vote up the one you chose.

Comment: I think that's another question that can't be actually answered. Maybe should be a community wiki.

Comment: yes, definitely community wiki

Comment: +1 to community wiki; also if Nick really wants the "yes/no" answers he should seed those responses.

Comment: @Portman: community wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been running the Beta as my primary OS for months now and its been great. There were a few issues early on but most have since been fixed. So yes, I will be running the release candidate as my primary OS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm considering it.

It can't be as bad as this RTM version of Vista I currently have!

Answer (score 1):

If initial feed back is good, I will be installing as my primary.  The increased performance over Vista will be a big win for me.

Answer (score 1):

If and when I get a new PC I will make the switch over (current desktop is still on XP 64 bit edition). I don't honestly see the need to upgrade my two laptops from Vista at this time, since they are primarily used for internet browsing and other minor activities. The necessity to go through a new install with them isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning to move my main desktop machine at home onto it, but on a new hard-drive and in dual-boot mode...

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to go about doing this?

Comment: when I find out, I'll let you know... :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely - I already run Windows 7 (64-bit) on absolutely all my machines. There is no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

i tried out the test on my MediaCenter pc.
and that worked really fine.

my only problem are the rumors that there will be a final in the summer.
reinstalling all the stuff again in 2 months is not what i prefer.

but i think after a long weekend, i definitly would be on the RC ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of testing one of my applications full-time in Windows 7, so I will be running Windows 7 RC as my main OS. Dog-fooding FTW.

Answer (score 0):

No.

I haven't had time to evaluate the beta version, and I don't have time to deal with the inevitable loss of time upgrading older systems and dealing with quirks.

I will be using it for any new systems I build, but will not be upgrading.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

I already have the beta as a primary OS since December, I think. I haven't had a single problem with it yet - it's working super. Much faster than both XP and Vista; Readyboost is far improved; etc.

All in all, I'm *extremely* pleased with Windows 7. I don't need the RC since I have the beta and it's working great - so I'll wait for the full version before formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I ghosted my previous partition, so as to give myself a good disaster recovery backup plan.

Then I went and fully installed 7100, and it's like butter. Absolutely no problems so far. Everything installed smoothly, EXCEPT for SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. That gave compatibility warnings, and the solution was to install SQL Server 2008 SP1. Worked fine.

The best part is that Xbox 360 streaming of avi/xvid/divx files actually works! Windows Media Player, in the betas, was not picking up those files correctly for display to the Xbox 360.

I am extremely pleased with Windows 7 build 7100. Very speedy, the eye candy is nice, and it's faster than Vista, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the beta for over a month. I really like it, I will most likely be installing the RTM to see what's new. The software seems stable and I have not had any issues using it as my primary OS.